# Create TypeScript interface for existing Node.js module for VS Code IntelliSense

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

Considering the following Node.js project structure:

```
- entities
    - customer.js
- node_modules
- typings
- index.js
- jsconfig.json
- package.json
```

When having a `entities/customer.js` like this:

```
function Customer() {
    this.firstname = null;
    this.lastname = null;
    this.orders = []
}

Customer.prototype.addOrder = function (order) {
    this.orders.push(order);
};)

module.exports = Customer
```

In `./index.js`, `entities/customer.js` is used:

```
let Customer = require('./entities/customer');
let customer = new Customer();
customer.firstname = "John";
customer.lastname = "Doe"; 
customer.addOrder({ amount: 5, product : 'Apple' })
```

How would I declare just an TypeScript `interface` to support VS Code IntelliSense to not only show `addOrder(param: any): void` and where would I put everything in its place?
I don't want to have a TypeScript implementation that replaces the current `Customer` module.

Of course, I could use JSDoc comments (thanks to Salsa language service in VS Code):

```
/**
 * @param {{amount: number, product: string}} order
 */
```

But I'm interested in the TypeScript version for understanding.

As a bonus I would like to be `order` of type `Order`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the d.ts file that looks like this:

```
declare module 'customer' 
{
    export class customer 
    {
        public firstName: string;
        public lastName: string;
        public addOrder(order: any): void;
    }
}
```

You can put it in any folder inside your root one. Lets say 'manual_typings'.

Then in your index.js:

```
let Customer = require('./entities/customer');

let c = new Customer();
c.addOrder(123);
```

And in your tsconfig.js set `"allowJs" = true`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this is declaring an implementation which I don't want. And order is still of type any.